# Operations using vectors of different lengths in R

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have two vectors of differing lengths in R:

```
x=1:10
y=1:20
```

Even though they are not the same length, R allows me to perform operations with both of them.

```
> y/x
 [1]  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
 [7]  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 11.000000  6.000000
[13]  4.333333  3.500000  3.000000  2.666667  2.428571  2.250000
[19]  2.111111  2.000000

> x + y
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
```

Why can I do this? What does this output mean? How does R do these calculations?

Comment: Your vector `x` is shorter than `y` so its values are being recycled to match the length of `y`; in this case your code is equivalent to `y/rep(x,2)`.

Comment: It means `y` is being divided by `x` :-)

Comment: Please read the [amazing R documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), section 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [amazingly-written documentation for R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf):

2.2 Vector arithmetic

```
c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1, 6.4, 21.7) -> x
y <- c(x, 0, x)
```

Vectors can be used in arithmetic expressions, in which case the operations are performed element
by element. Vectors occurring in the same expression need not all be of the same length. If
they are not, the value of the expression is a vector with the same length as the longest vector
which occurs in the expression. Shorter vectors in the expression are recycled as often as need be
(perhaps fractionally) until they match the length of the longest vector. In particular a constant
is simply repeated. So with the above assignments the command

```
v <- 2*x + y + 1
```

generates a new vector v of length 11 constructed by adding together, element by element, 2*x
repeated 2.2 times, y repeated just once, and 1 repeated 11 times.