# standard deviation in rnorm() in r

Tags: r, statistics, data-generation

Just wondering what `sd=1:10` really means in `rnorm` function (never seen this before) `u <- rnorm(mean = 0, sd = 1:10, n = 10)`. Is there any simple way to check each value of `sd` using `r` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a vector as *sd*, each value will be applied to each simulation until your *n* is reached, for example:

```
rnorm(mean = 0, sd = c(0,100000), n = 5)
 0.00 116963.06      0.00  25354.82      0.00
```

So the first value is from a normal distribution with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 0, the second value has a sd of 100.000, the third value has a `sd` of 0,...

In your example each value will be simulated from a normal distribution with a different `sd`, going from 1 to 10.

Comment: so how does `sd=1:10` work here and how is it related to your `sd=c(0,100000)` ? In other words, in your case, why does it apply interchangeably? In my case, does it apply in order from 1 to 10 or randomly pick any number from 1 to 10? with replacement or without replacement? sorry for bombarding questions. Just I need you to be more specific.

Comment: I used 0 and 100.000 just o show the difference, but yest it is applied in sequence. In my case where n > lenght(sd) will be applied interchangeably, this a R property, maybe this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852236/operations-using-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-r